# Calling @Controller methods once per request

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Is there a nice way to have Spring's `@Controller` classes to call a specific method once per request?

Right now I'm using a method annotated with `@InitBinder` for this purpose, but this is suboptimal as `@InitBinder` methods get called several times per request. I just want to do some initialization / update stuff to use in my controllers.

What I'm looking for is something like Rails' `before_filter`, but as far as I can tell there's no functionality like that in Spring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need a [request-scoped controller bean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-request). Spring will create a new instance of the controller for each request, and will initialize the bean each time using the standard mechanisms like `@PostConstruct`.

Comment: I already thought about such a solution, but I don't want to initialize my controllers on each request. I just want to do some small cleanup tasks (e.g. resetting some properties used inside my views). So this would be possible, but I hoped for a more clean solution.

Comment: Spring controllers are by default shared between threads and requests. If you have per-request state in your controller beans, then you should not share them between requests, and request-scoped beans are the cleanest and safest way to handle this.

Comment: Is there a way to autowire a request-scoped bean into a singleton-scoped controller?

Comment: Yes: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other-injection